# What does PvP logging mean in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing on a Minecraft server and a guy was killing other people and suddenly it said he was killed for **PvP logging**. What does that mean?

Answer (score 14):

"PvP Logging" describes the practice of logging out during PvP when it looks like you might lose. It isn't unique to Minecraft, but occurs in all competitive games where losing in PvP incurs any kind of penalty, even as slight as simply increasing your "death" count, thus reducing your kill-to-death ratio. In some cases (such as in Minecraft) simply closing your client or quitting the game instantly logs you out, even in combat; for others, it's a bit more complicated, but people found ways regardless.

There are a few plugins for Minecraft servers to combat this behaviour, like [CombatLog](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/combatlog/) and [PvP Tag](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/pvp-tag/) for Bukkit. They all have the problem that the Minecraft servers can't discern between someone trying to log out to save their hide and their clients simply crashing. As such, those plugins can lead to unfair situations as well, especially if somebody finds a way to crash someone else's client.

Answer (score 5):

PvP logging means logging out in the middle of a fight so as to avoid dying.  It is frowned upon on PvP servers and on some it is a bannable offense.

Comment: On some servers, they have a plugin which forces you to drop your items upon PvP logging.

Comment: aka rage-quitting

Comment: @ratchetfreak Not exactly, someone who logs out to not die is far from raging - they're trying to gain an unfair advantage in stats. I'd consider it closer to team-switching in COD 4 to avoid deaths.

Answer (score 0):

PvP Logging is where you are fighting someone and then they log out quickly before they die so they dont loose there stuff. Sometimes you will wait there or build a trap but others they dont come back on until like ages

Answer (score -2):

PvP Logging means that if people are almost dead, they will disconnect because they won't
lose their stuff on PvP servers.